# Test whether a CMakeLists.txt is used as a subdirectory

Tags: cmake

I want to write a `CMakeLists` that can be used not only as a sub-`CMakeLists` both also standalone. For example, in the following setup

```
a
├── b
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── CMakeLists.txt
```

with

```
$ cat a/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(b)
```

However, I'd also like to make `a/b/CMakeLists.txt` a standalone CMake file that can be used directly by `cmake`. In particular, `a/b/CMakeLists.txt` needs to perform a conditional initialization depending on how it is used. Basically something like this:

```
$ cat a/b/CMakeLists.txt
IF_INCLUDED # dummy
   DO_INIT()
ENDIF
# something else
```

So, I'm wondering

1. Is this something that people will do?
2. Is there a predicate like the aforementioned `IF_INCLUDE` (again, dummy)?

Answer (score 9):

I've seen such setup a few times, so it's certainly something people do. The most common way to phrase such a test is this:

```
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
```

(or the same with binary directories).

`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` is the directory containing the toplevel `CMakeLists.txt` (the one on which CMake was originally invoked). `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` is the directory containing the `CMakeLists.txt` currently being processed. If they are the same, it's guaranteed that the current CMakeList is the top-level one.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows. `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` lowercases the path, but `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` doesn't. I have no explanation on why it does so

Comment: @Justin I cannot reproduce such lowercasing (with CMake 3.7.2), neither from the command line nor in the CMake GUI. Can you provide a bit more info on how you're running CMake?

Comment: I did some more investigation. It turns out that you are correct (with CMake 3.12.1) and there is no lowercasing when directly running from the terminal (didn't try CMake GUI) or by running CMake server. However, when running via [VSCode CMake Tools](https://github.com/vector-of-bool/vscode-cmake-tools), it does. I'll try to investigate what CMake Tools is passing to CMake that makes it do that

Comment: CMake Tools normalizes the path to the source directory, which lowercases the path on Windows. When it invokes the CMake Server with that path, CMake takes the path and uses it for `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`. So it is *possible* to invoke CMake with a lowercased `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, but it's not something most people will encounter

Comment: @Justin Interesting investigation; I will try later today to incorporate it into the answer. Nevertheless, I would consider that a bug, either of VSCode CMake Tools or of the CMake Server; the reason is that comparisons like my answer shows are really quite widespread in projects out there, so they should work.

Comment: I consider it a bug in CMake Tools and a deficiency / bug in CMake. It's a bug in CMake Tools because case-sensitive directories exist in Windows (especially when the WSL is involved), but it's difficult to solve, since AFAICT, Windows provides no way to normalize paths. It's a deficiency in CMake since it really should have a `PATHEQUAL`, which would just solve the problem, and maybe a bug because it should probably normalize the source and binary dir it's given.

Comment: This may be related https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18862